How to get the surviving stabilisers of a fusion network
In Fig. 5 of PsiQuantum's Fusion-based quantum computation paper, it's clear to me how to get R, F, and C.
How do I get S? Just by looking at (a), I could obviously tell you that we end up with <X1X16, Z1Z16>, but I don't know why the other Xs and Zs are there or how I would do it if I didn't have the image of the fusion network to refer to. Does one arrive at S by multiplying elements of R together, or something along those lines?
This is my first intro to FBQC, so please forgive the basic question.


Equation 4 of of the paper defines $S=Z_R(F)$.
The generators of $R$ and $F$ are defined by the network and are given in Figure 5c.
The rest is some linear algebra to get $S$.
I was able to verify what's in the paper including the value of $S$ before and after all the measurements (equation 16)...(btw there are probably a few errors in this equation : $m_{a,b}^{XX}$ mixed up with be $m_{a,b}^{ZZ}$...)
Here's GAP code that does the calculation for the example in question :
R:=
[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]];

F:=
[[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]];

# C is intersection of R and F (equation 12)
C:=Intersection(VectorSpace(GF(2),R*Z(2)),VectorSpace(GF(2),F*Z(2)));
C:=BasisVectors(Basis(C));
C:=List(C,x->List(x,Int));

# symplectic null space of F : all paulis that commute with F
n:=16;
T:=NullspaceMat(TransposedMat(F*Z(2)));
T:=List(T,x->Concatenation(x{n+[1..n]},x{[1..n]}));

# limit to those in R (equation 4)
S:=Intersection(VectorSpace(GF(2),R*Z(2)),VectorSpace(GF(2),T*Z(2)));
S:=BasisVectors(Basis(S));
S:=List(S,x->List(x,Int));

Print("C=\n",C,"\n");
Print("S=\n",S,"\n");

running it (takes seconds) givse C and S; note that C is included in S as expected :
C=
[[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]]
S=
[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]]


could you explain what linear algebra leads to S?

the GAP code describes it : C=R^F; T=null(F'); S=R^T; (here ^ means intersection).
